# Problem in displaying pagination dots in owl carousel with multiple rows

Tags: php, jquery, css, yii2, owl-carousel

I have changed the owl-carousel to display in multiple rows so i have added co-md-12 class after every five items.In this way my all items from the loop is displaying but i want to display only 9 items in three rows and after i want pagination dots for next nine items like pagination.How can i do this?

I have tried dots: true and items:9 in my jquery but it's not working.

This is my code for carousel :

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="owl-carousel site-owl">
                <?php 
        if(!empty($Restaurants)){ 
          $count = 0;
          foreach ($Restaurants as $key => $restaurant) { ?>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="media d-block mb-4 text-center site-media site-animate border-0 restaurant_image">
                  <img src="<?php echo Yii::getAlias('@web')."../../../uploads/".$restaurant->photo?>" alt="Free Template by colorlib.com" class="img-fluid">
                  <div class="media-body p-md-5 p-4">
                  <!--   <h5 class="text-primary">$19.50</h5> -->
                    <h5 class="mt-0 h4"><?php echo !empty($restaurant->name) ? $restaurant->name : "-"; ?></h5>
                    <p class="mb-4"><?php echo !empty($restaurant->description) ? Common::get_substr($restaurant->description,70) : "-"; ?></p>

                    <p class="mb-0"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Read More</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                <?php $count++;
                if($count>=3)
                  {
                    echo "</div></div><div class='col-md-12'><div class='owl-carousel site-owl'>";
                    $count=0;
                  }

               ?>
        <?php }
          }
         ?>

         <!--    </div>
          </div> -->

        </div>
      </div>
```

And this is my js code :

```
var carousel = function() {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop: false,
            margin: 10,
            nav: true,
            stagePadding: 5,
            //autoWidth:true,
            nav: false,
            navText: ['<span class="icon-chevron-left">', '<span class="icon-chevron-right">'],
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items: 1
                },
                600:{
                    items: 2
                },
                1000:{
                    items: 3
                },
            }
        });
    };
    carousel();
```

I want three items on each row and total three rows i.e. 9 items in one page slide and after that i want pagination dots and again 9 items in next slide like pagination. Can it is possible to achieve this in owl carousel?

Comment: Hard to debug mate...

Comment: should i need to add more info?

Comment: I meant, can i see on live, how is this hapening?

Comment: These sliders usually need all slide items to be siblings in the original markup, I doubt this will work if you just introduce arbitrary grouping elements in between them yourself. _“I want three items on each row and total three rows i.e. 9 items in one page slide”_ - then see to it that you get _that_ - 3 rows with 3 columns each - wrapped into one single item.

Comment: @Kumar I have this code in my localhost. Not deployed yet.

Comment: @04FS  yes i have the same doubt. Is it feasible or not?

Comment: If you provide such 3x3 grids as items for the slider to use as I said, I don’t see why not.

Comment: Alternatively, you can look into a different slider library. Slick Slider for example has a “grid” mode that can be configured using the `rows` and `slidesPerRow` options. https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Ok let me try this first after i will use this alternative option. Thanks for your help.